# cassandra, which is best schema for user-related data?

Tags: cassandra

I want to store user related data and each chunk of data has it's own id. The id is the user id plus the id of the specific bit of information. Those data also are time based and reads will be say 50% as many as writes. I am thinking of using one of the following:

1. create table d1(id text,time bigint, data bigint, primary key (id,time)) with cluster order by (time desc)

here the id will be userid+data id, all in 1 string. This means that data for 1 user will be in different nodes.

1. create table d2(id text,dataid text, time bigint, data bigint, primary key (id,dataid,time)) with cluster order by (time desc)

here the id = userid and dataid is a cluster id. This means all data for a user will be in 1 node.

So for 1 request of this user, I might have to query for 2-3 or more of these rows.

Which will be the best approach in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're interested in some sort of time lookup since you're mentioning time series.  The answer depends on what type of query you're pursuing.

a) If you want to query all rows for a given user sorted by time, your second schema is better by far.  In the first schema your data is partitioned by user *and* dataid, and so you give up the ability to run fast queries per user, because various data for even that single user will be spread across the cluster (assuming you use the default partitioner).

b) If you want to query by user and dataid sorted by time (to get the history of changes for that single piece of data, let's say), schema 1 would be preferable for the same reasons as outlined in #1.

c) If you want to query by time globally, both schemas will be slow, because you'll need to scan multiple users (the whole cluster) to satisfy the query.

Lastly, writes will be comparatively fast no matter what schema you pick.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, regarding (b), what if I want to do say 5 queries for same user but different dataid sorted by time, is schema 1 still preferable?

Comment: It depends on the cardinality of your values.  For example: if each user potentially contains dozens of different dataids, then yes, issuing 5 separate queries with schema 1 and then, optionally, merging and sorting the results on the client side would be preferable.  If your user is likely to have only that many data ids in the first place (let's say up to 10), then it would be faster to use schema 2, get all rows for that user and then filter and possibly re-sort on the client side.

Comment: in my case, sorting could occur on the server side. So I usually care for the latest data per id and data id. "with cluster order by (time desc)" sets cassandra to order by time desc, so any query (even without an order clause) for a specific id and dataid will return the latest data first. But I am still unsure if schema 1 or 2 is better if I run say 5 queries for same user per request.

Comment: If those 5 queries will, in total, only return a small subset of all rows for that user, then schema 1 is better.  If you will be retrieving practically all rows for that user in those five queries, then schema 2 is better (just query for all rows for that user and filter away rows you don't need on the client).